# Nested query problem

Tags: linq

I have 3 classes in C#:

```
class Folder
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    List<File> files { get; set;}
}

class File
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    Author author { get; set; }
}

class Author
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of Folder items (List):

```
var folders = getAllFolders();
```

How can I use Linq to return a list of Folders from the list when i only know the Author id of the files?

I need the list to contain all folders where a given Author has created a file!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to find the folders where [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx) of the files have the Author id equal to the one you are looking for.

```
var authFolders = folders.Where( fo => fo.files.Any( fi => fi.Author.Id == authorId ));
```

Comment: @Kobi -- yep.  I keep saying that SO needs intellisense, but they keep ignoring me.  :-)